# Python speeding up the search for a value in a dictionary of ranges

Tags: python, search, dictionary, numpy, range

I have a file with a column of values I would like to use to compare with a dictionary that contains two values that together form a range.

for instance:
File A:

```
Chr1   200    ....
Chr3   300
```

File B:

```
Chr1    200    300    ...
Chr2    300    350    ...
```

For now I created a dictionary of values for File B:

```
for Line in FileB:
        LineB = Line.strip('\n').split('\t')
        Ranges[Chr].append(LineB)
```

For the comparison:

```
for Line in MethylationFile:
        Line = Line.strip("\n")
        Info = Line.split("\t")
        Chr = Info[0]
        Location = int(Info[1])
        Annotation = ""
        for i, r in enumerate(Ranges[Chr]):
            n = i + 1
            while (n < len(Ranges[Chr])):
                    if (int(Ranges[Chr][i][1]) <= Location <= int(Ranges[Chr][i][2])):
                        Annotation = '\t'.join(Ranges[Chr][i][4:])
                    n +=1
            OutFile.write(Line + '\t' + Annotation  + '\n')
```

If I leave the while loop the program does not seem to run (or is probably running too slow to get results) since I have over 7,000 values in each dictionary. If I change the while loop to an if loop the program runs but at an incredibly slow pace.

I'm looking for a way to make this program faster and more efficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries are great when you want to look up a key by exact match. In particular, the hash of the lookup key has to be the same as the hash of the stored key.

If your ranges are consistent, you could fake this by writing a hash function that returns the same value for a range, and for every value within that range. But if they're not, this hash function would have to keep track of all of the known ranges, which takes you back to the same problem you're starting with.

In that case, the right data structure here is probably some kind of sorted collection. If you only need to build up the collection, and then use it many times without ever modifying it, just `sort`ing a list and using the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module will do it for you. If you need to modify the collection after creation, you'll want something built around a binary tree or B-tree variant of some kind, like [`blist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) or [`bintrees`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/).

This will reduce the time to find a range from N/2 to log2(N). So, if you've got 10000 ranges, instead of 5000 comparisons, you'll do 14.

While we're at it, it would help to convert the range start and stop values to ints once, instead of doing it each time. Also, if you want to use the stdlib `bisect`, you unfortunately can't pass a `key` to most functions, so let's reorganize the ranges into comparable order too. So:

```
for Line in FileB:
    LineB = Line.strip('\n').split('\t')
    Ranges[Chr].append(int(LineB[1]), int(LineB[2]), [LineB[0])

for r in Ranges:
    r.sort()
```

Now, instead of this loop:

```
for i, r in enumerate(Ranges[Chr]):
    # ...
```

Do this:

```
i = bisect.bisect(Ranges[Chr], (Location, Location, None))
if i:
    r = Ranges[Chr][i-1]
    if r[0] <= Location < r[1]:
        # do whatever you wanted with r
    else:
        # there is no range that includes Location
else:
    # Location is before all ranges
```

You have to be careful thinking about `bisect`, and it's possible I've got this wrong on the first attempt, so… read the docs on what it does, and experiment with your data (printing out the results of the `bisect` function), before trusting this.

---

If your ranges can overlap, and you want to be able to find all ranges that contain a value rather than just one, you'll need a bit more than this to keep things efficient. There's no way to fully-order overlapping ranges, so `bisect` won't cut it.

If you're expecting more than log N matches per average lookup, you can do it with two sorted lists and `bisect`.

But otherwise, you need a more complex data structure, and more complex code. For example, if you can spare N^2 space, you can keep the time at log N by having, for each range in the first list, a second list, sorted by end, of all the values with a matching start.

And at this point, I think it's getting complex enough that you want to look for a library to do it for you.

---

However, you might want to consider a different solution.

If you use [`numpy`](http://numpy.org) or a database instead of pure Python, this can't cut the algorithmic complexity from N to log N… but it can cut the constant overhead by a factor of 10 or so, which may be good enough. In fact, if you're doing tons of searches on a medium-small list, it may even be *better*.

Plus, it looks a lot simpler, and once you get used to array operations or SQL, it may even be more readable. So:

```
RangeArrays = [np.array(a[:2] for a in value) for value in Ranges]
```

… or, if `Ranges` is a dict mapping strings to values, instead of a list:

```
RangeArrays = {key: np.array(a[:2] for a in value) for key, value in Ranges.items()}
```

Then, instead of this:

```
for i, r in enumerate(Ranges[Chr]):
    # ...
```

Do:

```
comparisons = Location < RangeArrays[Chr]
matches = comparisons[:,0] < comparisons[:,1]
indices = matches.nonzero()[0]
for index in indices:
    r = Ranges[indices[0]]
    # Do stuff with r
```

(You can of course make things more concise, but it's worth doing it this way and printing out all of the intermediate steps to see why it works.)

Or, using a database:

```
cur = db.execute('''SELECT Start, Stop, Chr FROM Ranges 
                    WHERE Start <= ? AND Stop > ?''', (Location, Location))
for (Start, Stop, Chr) in cur:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked with just one edit - when specifying `r = Ranges[Chr][i]` I had to change it to `r = Ranges[Chr][i-1]`

Comment: @user2165857: OK, thanks; I'll edit it. But make sure this is right in the case of empty ranges (e.g., you've got `3-10`, then `10-10`, then `10-21`, and you're searching for `10`—you should find `10-21`, not `10-10` there). Of course I'm assuming you're using typical Python half-open ranges, and that empty ranges are allowed…

Comment: @user2165857: Also, I'm pretty sure you need to deal with the case where the value is less than all ranges, because `bisect` will return `0`, and you'll check `Ranges[Chr][-1]`. And, while that will return the correct result, that's only because the value can't be in the last range, and I think that logic is a bit too opaque to rely on without comment.

Comment: Regarding your first comment - say I want to find all the ranges that contain `10`, do you have any suggestions about how to go about doing that?

Comment: I was assuming your ranges aren't overlapping. If they are, they can't be linearly ordered, which makes sorting and binary searching no longer a trivial solution. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still having some trouble. I tried to implement you numpy solution but keep getting and error for `comparisons = Location < RangeArrays[Chr]` : `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` I've never used numpy or arrays before and am not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @user2165857: This has nothing to with `numpy`; it's the pure Python part. (You should be able to debug that yourself by breaking down the line into pieces to see which one raises. Here it's `RangeArrays[Chr]`, and `RangeArrays` is just a list.) I didn't realize `Chr` is a string, so `RangeArrays` is supposed to be a dict, so I built a list instead. Just build a dict instead. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @abarnet: I still had some trouble using the arrays so I used your suggestion for databases and the program runs beautifully. The only problem is that it's exceedingly slow (about two hours for a file of about 7,000 entries compared to a database of a little over one million).